# replicate within list element to make nested list

Tags: r, list, nested

say we have

```
a <- list(letters[1:4],letters[5:6])
```

how can we duplicate within each element to get a list like

```
b <- list(list(letters[1:4],letters[1:4]),list(letters[5:6],letters[5:6]))
```

I could make an empty list, for a[1] and a[2] fill it with replicated vectors then add it all in one big list.

but i think there should be a quick way that I am missing?

i did

```
lapply(a, function(x){replicate(2,x, simplify=FALSE)})
```

but the indexing seems strange
e.g.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
lapply(a, function(X) rep(list(X), 2))
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "e" "f"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "e" "f"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `replicate` to each element in your list.  Here we do so with `lapply`:

```
lapply(a, replicate, n=2, simplify=F)
```

`n` and `simplify` are arguments forwarded by `lapply` to `replicate` (see `?replicate`).  This produces:

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "e" "f"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "e" "f"
```

Note we're showing the output of `str(...)` for clarity, not the actual result.